# Virtual environment libraries do not update in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

So I have a virtual environment created with `Anaconda`, and I've also installed it into Jupyter notebook as [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/create-virtual-environment-using-conda-and-add-it-to-jupyter-notebook-d319a81dfd1) link describes:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=<my_env_name>
```

However, whenever I install something new onto `my_env_name`, it doesn't work within the notebook. For example, I just did the following:

```
>>> pip install boto3 
>>> import boto3
```

This works in the anaconda prompt.

However, if I try to do `import boto3` in the notebook, I just get:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'

Why isn't the libraries syncing up? I actually ran the `ipykernel` command again as well to see if that would fix it, but nope. If I run `!pip install boto3` within the notebook, I just get a bunch of "requirement satisfied already". What could be the reason causing this issue?

Edit:

While checking the `sys.executable` I get:

> C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe

But I probably should be getting this, correct?

> C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\my_env_name\python.exe

Comment: I think environment may be out of sync

Execute `sys.executable` in Jupyter and Anaocnda and see the path of installed packages

Comment: @Suhas_Pote that would make sense, but how would I actually get it to be synced together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to install kernel within the required environment using

```
python3 -m ipykernel install --user
```

and then install required libraries within this environment. Just make sure `ipykernel` is installed in the `virtualenv`

---

If above solution does not work then you can try steps given below

*Step 1:* check the correct executable path of the anaconda environment.
Go on command line, activate the conda environment then check the correct executable path for the environment.

```
conda activate {envronment name}
```

then on python console,

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

For instance on Linux it will be

```
/media/{username}/{path-to}/anaconda3/envs/{environment name}/bin/python
```

*Step 2:* correct the executable path for jupyter sessions
From command line, check the path where kernel.json of your conda environment is located using below command

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

For instance on Linux it will be:

```
/home/{username}/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/{environment name}
```

Open the `kernel.json` located in that folder and replace the incorrect executable path, as shown below.

```
{
 "argv": [
  "REPLACE-THIS-WITH-THE-CORRECT-EXECUTABLE-PATH",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "heterodimers",
 "language": "python"
}
```